# Closing Android app during splash screen still opens feed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

Recently, the splash screen was taking a long time to complete for whatever reason, so I used the home button to exit from the app. A few seconds later, the feed activity started out of the blue. When recreating the bug, on my device, the home button causes the feed activity to be loaded 3-5 seconds later, and the back button the feed activity starts nearly immediately.

Steps to recreate:

1. Kill app if needed
2. Start app
3. During splash screen, press back or home
4. Wait...???
5. Feed activity starts

<sub>Using v0.1.41 on Stock Android 4.3</sub>

Comment: +1 Reproduced on 0.1.40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in 0.1.42 coming out later tonight, thanks.